# `tee` and `bash` process substitution order

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution, tee

I'd have supposed this code would have printed "*oof*" first:

```
echo foo | tee >(rev) | ( sleep 1 ; cat ; )
```

Output:

```
foo
oof
```

Increasing the `sleep` time doesn't change the order.  Why doesn't that work?

---

Note that other tools *do* work as supposed, *e.g.*: `echo foo | pee rev 'sleep 1 ; cat'`.

Comment: The output of `rev` goes through `cat` as well in `bash` (contrary  to `zsh`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In

```
echo foo | tee >(rev) | (sleep 1; cat)
```

In `bash` like in `ksh`, but unlike `zsh`, the stdout of `rev` also is the pipe to `(sleep 1; cat)`.

`echo`, `tee`, `rev` and the `(...)` subshell are started at the same time, but `tee` writes `foo\n` to stdout *before* the pipe to `rev`, so in any case, `rev` will write `oof` to the pipe after `tee` writes `foo`, so `oof` can only come last. Delaying `cat` has no incidence.

If you wanted the output of `rev` *not* to go through the pipe to `(sleep 1; cat)`, you'd use `zsh` or do:

```
{ echo foo 3>&- | tee >(rev >&3 3>&-) 3>&- | (sleep 1; cat) 3>&-; } 3>&1
```

Note that `zsh` also has a builtin `tee` in its `multios` feature, so you can do:

```
echo foo > >(rev) > >(sleep 1; cat)
```

However in:

```
echo foo > >(rev) | (sleep 1; cat)
```

The output of `rev` would go through `cat` (confusingly considering it doesn't in the `echo foo >(echo bar) | (sleep 1; cat)` case).

Comment: Thanks, I needed that!  For me this is one of those cases where I knew something, (prior experience juggling three or four pipelines), but failed to correlate it when needed, or perhaps hit my head somewhere...

Comment: @Stéphane, why do you close file descriptor 3 in every command? This example seems to run fine: `{ echo foo  | tee >(rev >&3 )  | tr a-z A-Z ; } 3>&1`

Comment: @arielCo For  cleaning.  They don't need  that fd 3.

Answer (score 1):

Using two `bash` process substitutions, (instead of just one, then a pipe), then dumping the STDOUT to /dev/null, works as expected:

```
echo foo | tee >(rev) >( sleep 1 ; cat ; ) > /dev/null ; sleep 1
```

Output:

```
oof
foo
```

Notes:

- the *2nd* `sleep` prevents "*foo*" from being printed after the command prompt.
- reducing the `sleep` delay number to some optimum ought to be better, but I'm not sure what that number should be.  `1` is a bit slow, but always seems to work; `.01` doesn't always work, (that is, the output is sometimes in the wrong order), `.1` seems to work well.